# docker compose integration tests without opening ports to host

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, integration-testing

I am using [spotify docker maven plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) and [docker-compose mvn plugin](https://github.com/dkanejs/docker-compose-maven-plugin) to write integration tests. The docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: "2.1"
   services:
      Service1:
          container_name: service1-host
          image: service1:latest
          ports:
          - "8081:8081"
      Service2:
          container_name: service2-host
          image: service2:latest         
          ports:
          - "8082:8082"
```

When running Integration tests with maven-failsafe-plugin my JUnit tests access these service1 and service2 through the ports. How can we avoid port conflicts if multiple builds are running on jenkins?

Is it possible to run integration tests within same docker network as service1 and service2?

Comment: You could create a local network within your docker-compose file...

Comment: @khmarbaise Docker Compose does that on its own.  That also doesn't address the port-mapping question at all.

Comment: It does simply cause if you make a network which the two services share you don't need to map the ports to the outside. This will keep the communication strictly inside the docker network. Also one question is: Are those app spring boot apps ?

Comment: apps are simple embedded jetty apps(not spring-boot). @khmarbaise i hope you understand that I would like to run integration tests in same local n/w ? any examples!